# Restrict users from my website to redirect to another website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to restrict users from my website to stop redirection to another website.
For example my website is www.paktutorial.com and there is a link to website www.google.com.
but i want that user do not navigate to google.com ( I want that link over there but do not  the redirection).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you disable the link. Show the link but disable them.

Comment: that's not possible. It is something coming out of jquery really complex code and written by someone else. I tried many things but not working. just I would like to stop navigation.

Comment: I understand it might be complex. But if you want to disable them, its just 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I understood from your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/84ATs/1/

HTML

```
<a href="www.google.com">link 1</a>
<a href="www.paktutorial.com">link 2</a>
```

JS

```
$('a').on("click", function(e){
  if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(window.location.host)==-1)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So basically I would look in the window's URL and see if the target URL of the anchor tag clicked has the same host, and if not, prevent the window from redirecting.​

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please refer the below HTML code snippet .
You need to define anchor tag in following manner.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>
```

Specifying javascript:void(0) in href property of anchor element will prevent its  default behaviour  since void operator returns null as a result of which browser will not be able to load new page.

For more documentation about javascript:void(0) please refer the documentation mentioned in below url
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptvoid.php